# I want to give an input of adding two numbers but it should return multiplication of those two numbers using operator overloading

Tags: python, python-3.x, operator-overloading

I am a newbie. I want to use operator overloading which gives 3+4 but returns answer of 3*4

I have made a class and passed two functions add and mul

```
class A: 
    def __init__(self, a,b): 
        self.a = a 
        self.b = b

    # adding two objects  
    def __add__(self, other): 
        return self.a + other.a , self.b + other.b
    # multiply two objects
    def __mul__(self, other):
        return self.a * other.a , self.b +other.b

ob1 = A(1) 
ob2 = A(2) 
ob3 = ob1+ob2
ob4 = ob1*ob2
print(ob3)
print(ob4)
```

Expected: input 3 and 4 , it should show 3+4 but return 3*4

Comment: You have an `__init__` that wants two elements, but you are only passing 1.

Comment: I am not sure but I have passed a and b , two elements. Sorry.please correct me if i am wrong!

Comment: `A(1)` and `A(2)` looks like one argument to me.

Comment: The two elements are relevant for the operator (`__add__` or `__sub__`) but make no sense for the `__init__`.

Comment: @StephenRauch can you please explain how to correct and proceed. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes I could.  But...  I don't really understand what you are trying to do.  Your question is not clear what you want.

Comment: in def__add__ i have to return multiplication not addition.

Comment: Why is that not just `self __add__(self, other): return self.a * other.a`?

Answer (score 0):

In your `__mul__` and `__add__` methods, you need to return an instance of `A`, not just some values (unless you are doing in place operations). It seems like you only want to add 2 numbers together, so maybe you should try having only 1 parameter `__init__`:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a

    def __add__(self, other):
        return A(self.a * other.a)
```

Now when you do:

```
A(3) + A(2)
```

You are getting back `2*3` as the `__add__` method returns a new instance of `A` whose `.a` attribute is the product, not sum, of the given two.

You should also consider type checking or error handling as your next step. What if I typed:

```
A(2) + 10   # not A(10)
```

Would an error be raised? That’s up to you. The easiest way to cause an error to be raised if you return `NotImplemented` from the function. This method also allows polymorphism to take place where any object with a `.a` attribute will work (as long as it is something that can be multiplied).

```
...
def __add__(self, other):
    try:
        return A(self.a * other.a)
    except Exception:
        return NotImplemented
```